# If condition with variable equal to zero

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, boolean

I have the following code:

```
if(!$a)
{
     //code that should run when $a is not set at all;
}
elseif ($a==0)
{
    //code that should run when $a is equal to 0;
}
else
{
    //code for all other cases;
}
```

The problem is, when $a equals to 0 php evaluates it as false and the first code runs. However, I need it to run the second code. How should i redo it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check to see if a variable *is set* use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset):

```
if(!isset($a))
```